# Can dplyr::case_when return mix of NAs and non-NAs?

Tags: r, dplyr

Can `case_when()` in `dplyr` return a mix of `NA` and non-`NA` values?

When I ask it to return `NA` in response to one statement, but an non-`NA` value in response to another statement, it throws an evaluation error:

E.g, I want `1` for all values of `cyl >= 6`, and `NA` for values of `cyl < 6`

```
> library("dplyr")
> mtcars %>% mutate(thing = case_when(cyl >= 6 ~ 1, cyl < 6 ~ NA ))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: must be type
>   double, not logical.

Alone, both of the statements evaluate fine.

This problem isn't present if asking for all NAs to be returned, but not a mixture of `NA`s and non-`NA`s.

E.g.: Return `NA` for all values of `cyl >= 6`

```
> mtcars %>% mutate(thing = case_when(cyl >= 6 ~ NA))
  cyl thing
1   6    NA
2   6    NA
3   4    NA
```

Looks good.

```
> mtcars %>% mutate(thing = case_when(cyl >= 6 ~ NA, cyl < 6 ~ NA ))
  cyl thing
1   6    NA
2   6    NA
3   4    NA
```

Cool.

```
> mtcars[1:3,] %>% mutate(thing = case_when(cyl == 6 ~ 1, cyl < 6 ~ NA, cyl > 6 ~ NA ))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>      Evaluation error: must be type double, not logical.

Not cool.

*NB: for clarity returned items in the examples are all from `mtcars[1:3,]` with `%>% select(cyl, thing)` at the end of the expression.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the problem with `class`.  We need `NA_real` to match the numeric type

```
mtcars %>% 
      mutate(thing = case_when(cyl >= 6 ~ 1,
                               cyl < 6 ~ NA_real_ ))
```

---

Also, for the second case

```
mtcars[1:3,] %>% 
       mutate(thing = case_when(cyl == 6 ~ 1, 
                                cyl < 6 ~ NA_real_, 
                                cyl > 6 ~ NA_real_ ))  %>%
       select(cyl, thing)
# cyl thing
#   6     1
#   6     1
#   4    NA
```

Comment: Yep, after reading TFM a dozen times *now* I see "All RHSs must evaluate to the same type of vector."